# Joint distribution of longest run and number of runs in a sequence of $n$ coin tosses?

Tags: probability, distributions, computational-statistics, runs

A coin with probability of heads $p \in (0, 1) $ is tossed $n$ times. **What is the joint probability distribution of the number of runs and the longest run?**

[Schilling (1990)](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/07468342.1990.11973306?journalCode=ucmj20) discusses the distribution of the longest run but I haven't found a good source for the joint distribution of the longest run and the number of runs. I also found [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/59738/83386) at Mathematics Stack Exchange.

As an illustration, I've randomly generated 10 coin tosses with a fair coin ($p=0.5$) and got the following sequence: $\text{TTHTHHTTHT}$. The longest run is 2 and the number of runs is 7.

Here is a simulation with 5000 repeats using $n=100$ and $p=0.5$:

[image: Simulation]

Here is the `R` code I used for the simulations and the graphic:

```R
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

res.frame <- data.frame(
  noruns = numeric(0)
  , longestrun = numeric(0)
)

n_sims <- 5000
set.seed(142857)

for (i in seq_len(n_sims)) {
  x <- rbinom(100, 1, 0.5)
  y <- rle(x)
  res.frame[i, "noruns"] <- length(y$lengths[y$length])
  res.frame[i, "longestrun"] <- max(y$lengths)
}

# Plot the data

theme_set(theme_bw())
p <- ggplot(res.frame, aes(x = noruns, y = longestrun)) +
  geom_point(position = position_jitter(width = 0.2, height = 0.27), size = 0.5) +
  labs(
    x = "Number of runs"
    , y = "Longest run"
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(2, 20, 2)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(20, 100, 5)) +
theme(
  plot.title=element_text(size=30),
  axis.title.y=element_text(colour = "black", size = 17, hjust = 0.5, margin = margin(0,12,0,0)),
  axis.title.x=element_text(colour = "black", size = 17, margin = margin(10,0,0,0)),
  axis.text.x=element_text(size=17, angle=0, hjust=0.5, vjust=1),
  axis.text.y=element_text(size=17),
  legend.position="none",
  plot.margin=unit(c(0.2, 0.2, 0.7, 0.2),"cm"),
  strip.text.x = element_text(size = 20),
  #         panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
  #         panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
  strip.background=element_rect(fill="white")
)

p
```

Comment: I like the density plot. What software did you use to generate it?

Comment: @jblood94 Thank you. I used R and ggplot2.

Comment: Sorry to bother--I've been Googling and browsing through the gallery, and I don't see that particular format. Do you know a search term I could use?

Comment: @jblood94 No problem. I added the code used. In the end, it's just a simple scatterplot with jittered points.

Comment: Ah, jitter. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the special case of $p=0.5$, the distribution is described by restricted integer compositions (see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/21650/697491)).
$$
F(n,k,w)=2^{1-n}\sum_{j=0}^k(-1)^j\binom{k}{j}\binom{n-jw-1}{k-1}
$$
where $n$ is the sequence length, $k$ is the number of runs, and $w$ is the maximum run length.

An R implementation:

```
fn <- function(n) {
  # using formulas for restricted integer compositions, returns the distribution
  # of maximum run length (rows) and number of runs (columns) of
  # Bernoulli sequences of length n with p = 0.5
  # (p. 441, formula E, http://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/14-5/abramson.pdf)
  if (n < 3L) return(diag(1/n, n)[,n:1, drop = FALSE])
  n1 <- n - 1L
  idx <- 2:n1
  m <- matrix(0, n, n)
  ones <- c(1, -1)
  coeff <- outer(1:n, 0:n, choose)
  lens <- outer(idx, idx, function(w, k) pmin(k + 1L, ((n - k) %/% w) + 1L))
  for (w in idx) {
    for (k in idx) {
      w1 <- w - 1L
      k1 <- k - 1L
      m[w, k] <- sum(coeff[k, seq_len(lens[w1, k1])]*coeff[seq.int(n1, by = -w, length.out = lens[w1, k1]), k]*rep(ones, ceiling(lens[w1, k1]/2))[seq_len(lens[w1, k1])])
    }
  }
  m[idx, idx] <- m[idx, idx] - m[1:(n - 2L), idx]
  m[1, n] <- m[n, 1] <- 1L
  m/2^n1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can calculate this distribution for any $p$ in terms of the function $T(k,m,n)$ which counts the positive integer sequences of length $k$, maximum at most $m$, and sum $n$.

The probability of having $2g+h$ runs (with $h\in\{0,1\}$), of maximum length $m$ in a sequence of $N$ coin flips with probability $p$ on each flip is:

$$
\sum_{j=1}^n 
\begin{cases}
\ \ \ \ T(g+h,m\phantom{-1}\ ,j)\,T(g,m\phantom{-1}\ ,N-j)\\
-\ T(g+h,m-1,j)\,T(g,m-1,N-j))
\end{cases}
{\Large\}}\left(p^j(1-p)^{N-j}+p^{N-j}(1-p)^j\right)
$$

For the probability mentioned in the question, this would be summed over $1\le g \le N/2$ and $0\le h\le 1$.

The expression can be broken down as follows:

- $T(g+h,m,j)$ counts the sequences of run lengths for whichever side came up first, if those $g+h$ lengths are all at most $m$ and sum to $j$.
- $T(g,m,N-j)$ counts the sequences of run lengths for whichever side came up second, if those $g$ lengths are all at most $m$ and sum to $N-j$.
- Their product counts sequences of all run lengths with $2g+h$ runs, all at most $m$ and summing to $N$.
- To count sequences of run lengths with maximum of exactly $m$, we subtract the product for $m-1$.
- Then we multiply by the probability of getting a sequence with the heads and tails specified according to those run lengths.

Finally, we can calculate $T(k,m,n)$ by a recursion:
\begin{align}
T(1,m,n) &= 1 \text{ if } n \le m\\
T(1,m,n) &= 0 \text{ if } n > m\\
T(k,m,n) &= \sum_{i=1}^{\min(m,n-1)} T(k-1,m,n-i)\ \ \text{ if }k > 1
\end{align}
The last equation counts all the possibilities with a last term of $i$.

So the overall probability comes from calculations of $T$'s with $1\le k\le \lceil N/2\rceil$, two values of $m$ and $1\le n\le N$, and involves at most ~$N^2$ calculations of $T$'s.